# How does 42 add up to -3?

Tags: support, questions, reputation

I gave a seemingly simple straight-forward answer and got +44 points and -2 points for it. Yet the answer has rested at -3. How is that possible? How does the math work to generate more positive points than negative points, yet the answer has a negative score? Normally each upvote = +10, and each downvote = -2. 
I can imagine that it received +50 points (5 upvotes) and -6-2=-8 (4 downvotes), which should place the answer at +1.

https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/38976/2430

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer has received 6 upvotes and 9 downvotes. Each upvote earned you 10 reputation points, which means you gained a total of 60 points. Each downvote cost you 2 points, which means you lost a total of 18 points.

```
60 - 18 = 42
```

Comment: That does indeed add up but the notifications are confusing. Where do you see the separate ups and downs?

Comment: @Chloe Click on the total score (the -3 in your case) to see the separate vote counts.

Comment: OMG  I did not know you could do that! Wow!

Comment: @Chloe It's part of the ["Established User" privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user). Another neat feature is the [post timeline](https://politics.stackexchange.com/posts/38976/timeline). Unfortunately, although it's accessible by everyone, there's no direct link to it for non-moderators. You'll have to build the URL yourself (/posts/<post_id>/timeline) every time you need to access it.